# PAM USB: require USB device only for some users

Tags: usb, authentication, pam

I have configured the pam_usb module on my Ubuntu 14.04.4 system. The current common-auth rules look like this:

```
auth    sufficient                  pam_usb.so
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

When my configured USB device is plugged in, I don't have to enter a password. If it's not plugged in, I can authenticate with my password.

But what I ideally want: For my user account, the USB device as well as my password is needed. For all other accounts (for which I have not configured a USB device) the password is enough to authenticate. Nobody should be able to log into my account without my USB dongle, but if I lose it and have to log in as root, that should work with just a (very strong) password.

If I set the USB rule to "required", no other user is able to log in since I don't have devices configured for them. That's not what I want.

Can you point me in the right direction? I can't work it out, the pam manual contains no example of a configuration like this afaik.